# How to copy strings collected from a file into a new array for console output in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, file

I am trying to copy a string array "buff" which holds exactly 1000 lines of "OK" in it. i want to copy buff array into line array but cannot see all the 1000 lines in console output. 
Here goes my code:

```
FILE *fp;
char buff[1000];

char* line[1000];

fp = fopen("protocol1.seq", "r");
int i;

for(i=0;i<=999;i++){        
    fgets(buff,sizeof(buff),fp);
    line[i] = buff;
    printf("%s",line[i]);
}

fclose(fp);
```

Comment: It could be helpful do describe what you see. Take care that all `line[i]` point to the same pointer `buff`.

Comment: Theoretically, you cannot see the difference between 1000 lines where all say "OK", and *one* line printed 1000 times.

Comment: Yes but i could see its not printing 1000 lines of "OK"

Comment: Maybe the console have less capacity. Did you try to pipe to `wc -l` or redirect to a file and open with your favorite editor ?

Comment: I must admit i do not have much experience with C so i do not know how to redirect console output to a file.

Comment: Redirecction is not a C feature, but your OS. Just do it from your console. `man bash` (or whateer your shell might be). An even better idea might be to `wc -l` (count the number of lines). Also, check the results `fopen`, `fgets` return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an array `line[]` which can hold pointers to up to 1000 lines, and you have an array `buff` which can hold one line (of up to 999 characters).  But you have nowhere to hold 1000 different lines.  As written, your `line` array will end up containing a bunch of copies of the exact same pointer, all pointing to `buff`, which will contain a copy of just the last line you read.

One way to fix this would be to call `malloc` to allocate memory for each line as you read it:

```
fgets(buff,sizeof(buff),fp);
char *buffcopy = malloc(strlen(buff) + 1);
if(buffcopy == NULL) {fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n"); exit(1); }
strcpy(buffcopy, buff);
line[i] = buffcopy;
```

Answer (score 1):

you've got a few errors.

Should you need to store all lines in an array it needs 2 dimensions, line and string.

So

```
char buff[1000][256];
```

Is probably what your looking for this gives 1000 lines of length 255,   the final character space is for the nul byte.

Although char *line[1000] is valid it's not what you mean, was this your first attempt to get a 2d array?

Now use 256 instead of sizeof(buff) as buffer control in fgets.

In c you cannot assign strings with the = operator nor compare with ==, you use strcpy and strcmp respectively.

Rather than printing on the fly in the read loop ,  it may make debug and development easier to have a print function.

To avoid a weird segmentation fault it makes sense to initialise your array. Use memset setting all bytes to 0

For future reference the format %s prints all characters upto the nul byte, so printf-ing an uninitialised string can cause undefined behaviour, probably a segmentation fault, not always but occurring sometime after the offended %s